# Why cover coals in the Temple, and what if the cover was needed?

Tags: shabbat, beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, fire-burning, maseches-tamid

The *mishna*, [*Tamid* 5:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%94_%D7%94), indicates that there was a large container used for several things in the Temple. Two of those were that it covered hot coals that spilled on the floor every Sabbath morning, and that it covered a [*tamei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumah_and_taharah) animal if one were found on Sabbath.

My kid asked:

- Were there more than one of these containers? If not, how did it cover an animal if it was covering the coals? Even if it covered the coals only for a while (see next bullet point), what if an animal was found during that time?
- Why did they need to cover the coals? (I suggested that maybe it was so no one would burn himself — which may indicate they were only covered for a while — but that I was unsure and presumably anyone walking by would see the coals.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All utensils in the Mikdash had multiple *copies*. It's an explicit Mishna in Chagiga - last Mishna ([3:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%97)), actually:

> כל הכלים שהיו במקדש, היו להם שניים ושלישים; אם נטמאו הראשונים, יביאו השניים תחתיהן.‏

So they surely had a few large containers and they could use them all if needed.

As to why they covered the coals? As you said, you don't want anybody getting burned:

- It's a Mitzva to remove dangerous objects וְלֹא-תָשִׂים דָּמִים בְּבֵיתֶךָ (Devorim כב)
- Cohanim we always running around - כהנים זריזים הם
- The floor of the Mikdash was not clean; see Mishna 5:7 in Pesachim that on Erev Pessach they would wash it. So the Cohen may not have a choice but to step on something - and we wouldn't want him to get burned.